# Pass config data using forRoot

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-aot

I am trying to pass config data into a custom library in Angular.

**In the users application**, they will pass some config data to my library using `forRoot`

```
// Import custom library
import { SampleModule, SampleService } from 'custom-library';
...

// User provides their config
const CustomConfig = {
  url: 'some_value',
  key: 'some_value',
  secret: 'some_value',
  API: 'some_value'
  version: 'some_value'
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    // User config passed in here
    SampleModule.forRoot(CustomConfig),
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    SampleService
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

**In my custom library**, specifically the `index.ts`, I can access the config data:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { SampleService } from './src/sample.service';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  exports: [...]
})
export class SampleModule {
  static forRoot(config: CustomConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    // User config get logged here
    console.log(config);
    return {
      ngModule: SampleModule,
      providers: [SampleService]
    };
  }
}
```

**My question is how do I make the config data available in the custom library's `SampleService`**

Currently `SampleService` contains the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {

  foo: any;

  constructor() {
    this.foo = ThirdParyAPI(/* I need the config object here */);
  }

  Fetch(itemType:string): Promise<any> {
    return this.foo.get(itemType);
  } 
}
```

I have read through the docs on [Providers](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#providers), however the `forRoot` example is quite minimal and doesn't seem to cover my use case.

Comment: were you able to pass map to your custom config? something like this myMap: Map<string, string[]>;  I am trying to pass a map but it doesn't work if I switch on AOT (ng serve --AOT)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You are almost there, simply provide both `SampleService` and `config` in your module like below:

```
export class SampleModule {
  static forRoot(config: CustomConfig): ModuleWithProviders<SampleModule> {
    // User config get logged here
    console.log(config);
    return {
      ngModule: SampleModule,
      providers: [SampleService, {provide: 'config', useValue: config}]
    };
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {

  foo: string;

  constructor(@Inject('config') private config:CustomConfig) {
    this.foo = ThirdParyAPI( config );
  }
}
```

**Update**:

Since Angular 7 `ModuleWithProviders` is generic, so it needs `ModuleWithProviders<SampleService>`

Comment: Great answer! I usually use it but instead of `string` i prefer using `OpaqueToken(InjectionToken)`

Comment: Thanks :). I find `OpaqueToken` too cumbersome to explain, but you are right of course. It's the preferred way. It's actually now `InjectionToken` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/InjectionToken-class.html

Comment: _Not_ using `InjectionToken` actually illustrates the flexibility of the injector. It also demonstrate usages of the `@Inject(dep)` pattern which is highly useful.

Comment: This works well. Very much appreciated. Will be looking into `InjectionToken` as well

Comment: I guess that you don't need the `Injectable`  decorator in the class if you have only one dependency and you are using the `Inject` decorator to instruct Angular what to inject.

Comment: @Jaime I don't know. It's considered good practice to just always add `@Injectable()` if the class is used as a service.

Comment: @Jaime exactly. It's surprising when adding a parameter to a constructor breaks your application. You make life easier for yourself and your coworkers if you just aleays add it ;-)

Comment: Should the providers line be this instead:

`(providers: [SampleService, {provide: 'config', useValue: config}]`

Comment: @NikoKonstantakos, I think it's correct as I have it in my answer. Why do you think it is not correct?

Comment: Because you're specifying the class name rather than the actual instance of the object, right?

Comment: In my code the value `const CustomConfig = { ... }` would be injected, your code example should cause an error, because there is no `config` in scope. Perhaps in my code the provider should be added to `AppModule` instead of `SampleModule` to make it more clear.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `Injectable` is such an awful name and `@Injectable()` is such an ugly syntax. It should be `inject` or `injected` and the syntax should be `@injected`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad that's just bikeshedding :D and I don't think your examples are better. `@Injectable()` marks a class to make it injectable, so the name isn't that bad.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that's not what `@Injectable()` does. It marks a class such that _its_ dependencies can be injected. What makes the class _itself_ injectable is listing it in the `providers` config array of an `NgModule`. Granted, I like to bikeshed ;), but that's not the case here. I also don't like the parens. Why is Injectable a _decorator factory_ and not a _decorator_? (this last point is bikeshedding :D)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer PS: I'm not sure if it works that way in Angular Dart. If I ever write an Angular app again, I will use Dart since I can't use Angular with JavaScript anymore.

Comment: In Dart there is no `forRoot` and no modules, at lrast not in the sense of Angular TS modules.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer sounds like a better design.

Comment: With this configuration, when building AOT I'm getting `NullInjectorProvider` error, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881070/aot-ngmodule-provider-with-dependencies-nullinjectorerror

Comment: What if have nested modules, how can I pass the config? I mean I can't use in AppModule: `imports: [ModuleA.forRoot(parentConfig)]` and then in ModuleA have `imports: [ModuleB.forRoot(parentConfig.childConfig)]`.

Comment: This requirement sounds a bit odd to me. Could not a service in `ModuleA` that is injected in services in `ModuleB` provide the information if `ModuleB` needs it?

Comment: Why should we use `static` keyword for `forRoot` definication?

Comment: @Harish because otherwise you would first need to create an instance of `SampleModule` to be able to pass the function reference and with `static` this is not necessary.

Comment: Hello @GünterZöchbauer, would above cause `config` to be available in the entire app (i.e. root injector) or will `config` only be provided module-wide?

Comment: That's the purpose of `forRoot`. If you don't want that then provide it in `providers` of a module or component.

Comment: @Top-Master thanks for the intention but that is the sole purpose of `forRoot` and I don't think it's necessary to mention that in my answer explicitly.

Comment: I remember that there were seveal such questions some years ago when Angular appeared. I think you need to load that either outside Angular before Angular starts or depending on your concrete use case using `APP_INITIALIZER` might be an easier option.

Comment: ModuleWithProviders expects generic of type module, `ModuleWithProviders<SampleModule>`

Comment: Does this still work for later releases of Angular11?  When I put my LibraryModule.forRoot(libConfig) - the compiler wants a <Routes> type insertion, then argument libConfig is not assignable to routes.