# InjectionToken for config not working with AoT

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm writing an Angular library where I need to **pass in a configuration object in the `.forRoot()`** of the module import.

I'm trying to do this (the apparently correct way) with `InjectionToken`, but getting an AoT compilation error.

Error when compiling with AoT:

> error TS4050: Return type of public static method from exported class
>   has or is using name 'InjectionToken' from external module
>   "/path/to/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/injection_token"
>   but cannot be named.

Any help is appreciated.

**module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CONFIG, Config } from './config';

@NgModule({ ... })
export class SomeModule {
    static forRoot(config?: Config) {
        return {
            ngModule: SomeModule,
            providers: [
                { provide: CONFIG, useValue: config }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

**config.ts:**

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const CONFIG = new InjectionToken<Config>('config');

export interface Config {
    some?: string;
    values?: string;
    here?: string;
}
```

**Desired usage by another application:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeModule } from 'some-library';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SomeModule.forRoot({
            // <-- config values here
        })
    ]
})
```

(Angular 5, TypeScript 2.6.2)

Comment: This answer might be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293449/3055401

Comment: Thanks, but that avoids the issue by getting rid of `InjectionToken`.  From what I've read, best practice is to use `InjectionToken` over strings.

Comment: My guess is that you must (and should anyway) specify the type returned by the forRoot method: `: ModuleWithProviders`.

Comment: 0_0 That was it, JB.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer by **JB Nizet** in comments above...

Needed to specify the type returned by the forRoot method, `ModuleWithProviders`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CONFIG, Config } from './config';

@NgModule({ ... })
export class SomeModule {
    static forRoot(config?: Config): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SomeModule,
            providers: [
                { provide: CONFIG, useValue: config }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```