# AOT NgModule provider with dependencies, NullInjectorError

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, angular2-aot

I've tried the implementation in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293449/513570:

```
@NgModule()
export class SampleModule {
  static forRoot(config: CustomConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    // User config get logged here
    console.log(config);
    return {
      ngModule: SampleModule,
      providers: [SampleService, {provide: 'config', useValue: config}]
    };
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {

  constructor(@Inject('config') private config:CustomConfig) {
```

```
const sConfig = {
    key: 'value'
};


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
        SampleModule.forRoot(sConfig),
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        ...,
        // { provide: SampleService, useFactory: () => new SampleService(sConfig) 
    ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If the service is imported in `providers` (commented code) instead of `imports`, all works fine in development and AOT.

But the given code only code works fine in development mode. In AOT it raises the following error:

```
StaticInjectorError[l]: 
  StaticInjectorError[l]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for l!
```

I've been serving with live-reload and preserve log in chrome while compiling the app and at some point (before mangling I suppose) the error is:

```
StaticInjectorError[SampleService]: 
  StaticInjectorError[SampleService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for SampleService!
```

I've also tried to provide with `export const SampleServiceToken = new InjectionToken<string>('SampleService');`

The only way it works is to provide the service in the main app @NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        { provide: SampleService, useFactory: () => new SampleService(config) },
    ],
})
```

dependencies:

```
"@angular/common": "5.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
"@angular/core": "5.0.3",
"@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
"@angular/http": "5.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
"@ionic-native/core": "^4.4.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
```

Comment: Display the place where you are using the SampleModule, I mean where and how are you importing it

Comment: @GogaKoreli done